# SSRS PDF file link not working

Tags: reporting-services, pdf-generation, ssrs-2008

I've created a SSRS 200R2 standard edition report that has been exported into PDF format.
The link does not work in the PDF file. What is strange is it works in Excel.
I have chosen the radio button **Go to report** in the text box properties dialog action page. The link is in a matrix total field.

Unsure if this is considered a hyperlink or drillthrough link?

**http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255291**

**Drillthrough Links**
Drillthrough links are not supported in PDF rendering. The drillthrough links are not rendered as clickable links and drillthrough reports cannot connect to the target of the drillthrough.

**Hyperlinks**
Hyperlinks in reports are rendered as clickable links in the PDF file. When clicked, Acrobat will open the default client browser and navigate to the hyperlink URL.

Do you know of a way for it to work in PDF format or do I have to use **Go to URL**?

Comment: Hiya, welcome to SO! As far as I know, there's no specific issues with SSRS around this, so it's probably due to something specific to your situation. Can you perhaps edit the question and add some more details? (E.g. what expression is creating the link, does it work in rendered html/word, how you are exporting to that format, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

When you choose the option Go To Report, that's considered to be a drillthrough link.

Go to URL is considered to be a hyperlink. It's not specific to a report. It can be anything. But you can generate a URL for the report that you were using with Go To Report. You just need to add the report server's Web service URL. So let's say you have a server named MyServer and you use the default Web Service name, reportserver. You want to link to report My Other Report in folder My Report Folder. Your URL needs to look like this:

```
http://MyServer/reportserver/My Report Folder/My Other Report
```